# jQuery works, then it doesn't anymore

Tags: jquery

I have a function in my main to load a dialog box:

```
<a href="#" class="insert" onclick="return openDialog('AddEditUser.aspx',350);">Add new</a>
```

This works because all the jquery script are loaded at the start of the main and I have defined the openDialog function.

But inside 'AddEditUser.aspx', the page that is opened, there is this code to close the dialog box at the end:

```
string script = @"jquery('#dialog').html('');jquery('#dialog').dialog('destroy');window.location.reload()";
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, typeof(UpdatePanel), "jscript", script, true);
```

And when I run the program, I always get the error "Runtime-error Microsoft JScript: Object expected" at this last jquery code sequence.

I googled the error and it says you get this because jquery isn't loaded but it is because the dialog box opened. What is the cause of this error?

Comment: Stack Overflow tells you how to format your code when you post it.

Comment: This doesn't happen to be in a SharePoint website does it?

Comment: Use IE's Developer Tools to get better information about the problem.

Comment: No it's not in a SharePoint website. And the strange part is that it used to work.. and then the day after it didn't anymore.

Comment: I think we need to see more of your code to understand what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

What does `openDialog` do? I believe it opens a new window and loads the page you pass to it. Are you sure you have jQuery on the new page(`AddEditUser.aspx`) you are trying to open? I see the issue is because it is not finding jQuery in the new page.

Also you shouild wrap the inline js in $(function(){})`just to ensure that dom is ready and`#dialog`is available to`jQuery`. Try this

```
string script = @"jquery(function(){jquery('#dialog').html('');jquery('#dialog').dialog('destroy');window.location.reload();});";
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, typeof(UpdatePanel), "jscript", script, true);
```